# Dxhtml scheduler v4.4 resize of lightbox

Tags: lightbox, scheduler, dhtmlx

Is there a way to change the width and the height of a Lightbox(the box for edit an event)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Height of lightbox controls can be changed using a `height` property in section config:

```
scheduler.config.lightbox.sections =  [
    {name: "description", height: 50, map_to: "text", type: "textarea"},
    {name: "time", type: "time", map_to: "auto"}
]
```

demo: http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/7d3ad241e

You can also access them and change their height dynamically. In that case, you'll also need to call scheduler.setLightboxSize to reset the total lightbox height;

demo: http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/7434db034
https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_setlightboxsize.html

As for the width of the lightbox, it can be changed via css -
 http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/fe8375043 (see HTML tab)